# Blender Cloud Generator Edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, volumetrics

I am trying to figure out how to solve a rendering issue with using the Cloud Generator plugin.

The image below is the result of applying the cloud generator (addon that comes with Blender) to a square.

The like the result but I can't figure out why when I render it with Cycles that it has these weird edging artifacts, as I circled in my attached image.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Rendered square with applied Cloud Generator]

Comment: I ran into the same issue and figured out that it had something to so with the orientation of the camera in regard to the cloud mesh. Everything that is non-orthogonal to the camera works for me.

Answer (score 3):

That's due to the *step size* being too large. Volume rendering works by a process called [ray marching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_ray_casting). In short, the volume is sampled at various distances and summed to get the total light coming from that bit of volume. The *step size* controls the distance between these samples.

In general, the bigger the step size, the fewer places the volume needs to be sampled, so the faster the render time. However, in return, you get these slicing artifacts.

[image]

To fix it, try lowering the step size in *Properties > Render > Geometry > volume sampling* (2.7x), or *Properties > Render > Volumes* (2.8).